# Place a floating div just next to image

Tags: html, css

I am making web dashboard similar to discord ui, I kinda achieved it by making a `span`, but the problem is I am using `position: fixed` and it is letting my hovering div getting underneath.

Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/5mv89wyg/1/

Comment: The minimal code to reproduce your problem belongs _directly_ into your question, in text form & properly formatted (stack snippet, when applicable), please do not just dump it onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the `margin-top: -40` aswell, see below:

```
.server:hover > span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Then the span element will appear next to the server item.

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6svfpr8/